# want to install mongodb on cloud9 local server

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose, mongodb-query

[screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zC1fA.png)

I am trying to install Mongo DB on my local server. I installed MongoDB on my workspace as shown below. But on running MongoDB, it shows an error."./mongod: line 1: mongod: command not found".

[]code- 

`bittukr:~ $ ls
lib/  workspace/
bittukr:~ $ mkdir data
bittukr:~ $ ls
data/  lib/  workspace/
bittukr:~ $ echo 'mongod --bind_ip=$IP --dbpath=data --nojournal --rest "$@"' > mongod
bittukr:~ $ ls
data/  lib/  mongod  workspace/
bittukr:~ $  chmod a+x mongod
bittukr:~ $ ls
data/  lib/  mongod*  workspace/
bittukr:~ $ ./mongod
./mongod: line 1: mongod: command not found`

Comment: Go to mongo db directory, and then go to bin folder, then use this command or add this to environment path variable.

Comment: i tried but stilll not working

Comment: which server you are using ?

Comment: actually m using local server of cloud9

Comment: go trough [this link](https://community.c9.io/t/setting-up-mongodb/1717)

Comment: i tried this link. you can see the screenshot which  i have mentioned in my question and stil its not working.

Answer (score 0):

I was experiencing the same issue, can you try reinstalling the mongodb package using the following command:

```
sudo apt-get install -y mongodb-org
```

I followed the link belows instructions and it appears to be working for me now: https://community.c9.io/t/setting-up-mongodb/1717

Answer (score 0):

use these command to install mongodb

```
sudo apt install mongodb-server-core
sudo apt install mongodb-clients
```

also, remove the --rest